# How to recover X11 connection without exiting R on remote server

Tags: r, ssh, x11-forwarding, xquartz

**Short version**: How do you restart a lost X11 connection from within R when working on a remote machine ?

**Long version**:

1. ***The setup***

I work with Mac 11.1 and connect to a remote Linux server to code in R (through [Nvim-R](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R)). The steps I use are usually:

```
ssh -Y login@remote.server
screen -r my_R_work_session
conda activate my_environment
nvim code.r
```

and then type `\rf` command to open a R terminal within `nvim`.

Then I am able to plot anything in R (eg. with `plot(iris)`). The plot pops up in an external window (through `X11` / `XQuartz`) on my Mac. It usually works fine at the beginning.

2. ***The problem***

But at some point, I might lose the connection to the server for just a second (internet failure, vpn stops...), and everything seems to work fine when I get back the connection to the server (main `ssh` connection is maintained) **except the X11 connection**.

At this point, the output of any `plot(iris)` would be:

```
Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  :
  unable to start device X11cairo
In addition: Warning message:
In function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''
```

3. ***The solution (but looking for something better!)***

The only solution I found for the moment is starting a new ssh connection to the server and re-do the whole process up to starting the R session and plotting stuff. Sometimes, closing only the `screen` session works, but I still need to reload `conda` and my `R` session. But it's time-consuming (and annoying) and my guess is that there might be a better solution.

4. ***What I have also tried (but doesn't change anything)***

I found many posts googling this error, but still nothing that could resolve this issue.

**- Check `capabilities()`**

Before losing X11 connection, the output of `capabilities()` is:

```
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

After losing X11 connection, the only difference is then that `X11` is set to `FALSE`.

**- Check `DISPLAY`**

Refering to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31283/error-in-r-unable-to-open-connection-to-x11), I checked `DISPLAY` but everything seems to be fine.
In terminal (before starting R or while r is running):

```
> echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

In R:

```
> Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")
localhost:10.0
```

And I tried setting `Sys.setenv("DISPLAY"=":0.0")` but does not make any difference.

**- `X11UseLocalhost`**

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83949/with-ssh-x11-forwarding-ssh-x-get-cant-open-display-trying-to-run-x-app) suggests changing `X11UseLocalhost no` to `X11UseLocalhost yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but it does not make any difference to me.

**- `Xpra`**

Finally, I tried using `Xpra` following the suggestions from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/reattach-to-lost-x11-session/10598) (probably the most promising one) but did not make any difference either. Although here I am not sure if I use it properly. Here is what I did:

```
[local] ssh -Y login@remote.server
[remote] screen -r xpra
[remote] xpra start :10
# exit screen
[local] xpra attach ssh:remote.server:10 
[remote] screen -r my_R_work_session
[remote] conda activate my_environment
[remote] nvim code.r
```

Thanks a lot for any comment and help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone bumping into this post, I ended up finding a super simple solution: you just need to start a new `ssh -Y` connection in parallel of your current session. Then you can redirect the `DISPLAY` parameter in the current session to the value in the new connection.

Here is a more detailed example.
In the current session (before starting the new ssh connection), if you try in  `R` terminal :

```
> capabilites()             # returns X11 = FALSE 
> Sys.getenv('DISPLAY')     # returns localhost:xx.0
localhost:12.0
> x11('localhost:12.0')     # returns error message
```

Now you start the new ssh connection in parallel: `ssh -Y login@remote.server`. You need to find the value of `DISPLAY` in this new session, eg:

In bash:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:13.0
```

Or in R:

```
> Sys.getenv('DISPLAY')
localhost:13.0
```

Finally, in the original R terminal, set the `DISPLAY` parameter to the new connection value:

```
> Sys.setenv('DISPLAY' = 'localhost:13.0')
> x11('localhost:13.0')  # or x11() - both should work
```

There is also another option, is to modify the value of `ForwardX11Timeout` in ssh config file (`~/.ssh/config`). It is usually set to ~20 min by default (see `man ssh`). You can try set this to one day (or more), eg: `ForwardX11Timeout 1d`. This will prevent `X11` to stop during any work session if it's opened less than 24 hours. You can even set `ForwardX11Trusted yes` in this config file. However, these options can lead to security leaks, so they need to be considered with care.